# Consolidate SQL query with 2 subselects with same where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

My app uses a scores table with a locationId, scoreDateTime, score, and comment columns.  Users can score a location and optionally submit comments.  A small data set might look like the following:

```
mysql> select locationId, scoreDateTime, score, comments from scores;
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------+
| locationId                  | scoreDateTime           | score | comments                       |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------+
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 17:30:32.899 |     3 | asdfasf                        |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 18:28:46.221 |     3 |                                |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 18:29:56.395 |     3 | safasf                         |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 18:32:10.358 |     3 |                                |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 18:49:32.262 |     3 |                                |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 18:50:33.693 |     3 |                                |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 19:13:58.456 |     3 |                                |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ | 2016-04-17 19:28:10.435 |     3 | asdfasf                        |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRhatfHL4GYe0 | 2016-04-17 23:20:28.857 |     3 | aasdfasfsfsd                   |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRhatfHL4GYe0 | 2016-04-17 23:22:55.254 |     3 | asdfasfasfsafasfsfasf asdfasfd |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRhatfHL4GYe0 | 2016-04-17 23:40:37.106 |     3 |                                |
| ChIJpbSR1a4I44kRemEzTpniis8 | 2016-04-19 11:17:41.836 |     5 | adfgadf                        |
| ChIJF1LAoqgI44kR5EWvRqJPUN4 | 2016-04-19 11:17:52.536 |     4 |                                |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------+
```

I'd like to build a single query that will get the following for each location:

- a score count from the last X hours
- a comment count from the last Y days
- the latest scoreDateTime (or NULL) for any comments in the last Y days

My motivation is to show locations, their recent score counts, their historical comment counts, and their latest comment datetime (or null).  This will give me the recent running score counts and the hotness of the comment trail.

The following query works.  However, the duplicate locationId list is actually going to be much higher in production.  **QUESTION: I'd like to know if there is a performant way to consolidate the 2 locationId lists, a.k.a 'locationId in (...)'.**

```
select
   x.locationId, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, IFNULL(commentCount,0) as commentCount, lastCommentDateTime
from

   ( select
        locationId,
        sum(if (score = 1, 1, 0)) count1,
        sum(if (score = 2, 1, 0)) count2,
        sum(if (score = 3, 1, 0)) count3,
        sum(if (score = 4, 1, 0)) count4,
        sum(if (score = 5, 1, 0)) count5
     from
        scores
     where
        scoreDateTime > '2016-04-16 21:38:51.843' and
        locationId in (
           'ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ',
           'ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRhatfHL4GYe0',
           'ChIJCes00a4I44kRKG8zB4KvYTM',
           'ChIJP-eRLq8I44kRKU6VOpTXqTM',
           'ChIJpbSR1a4I44kRemEzTpniis8',
           'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kRip2l7rjO2g4',
           'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kR5EWvRqJPUN4',
           'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kRRD_ZvPUmrGA',
           'ChIJjweq4h0G44kRWoCPQKPdrPM',
           'ChIJf2tVDB4G44kRTYjhl3sjm8M',
           'ChIJ_Vg4giEG44kRq2nvtjEn8yA',
           'ChIJP00qFSMG44kRyKcy2f_S12o'
        )
     group by locationId
   ) as x

left join

   ( select
        locationId,
        count(comments) as commentCount,
        max(scoreDateTime) as lastCommentDateTime
     from
        scores
     where
        comments != "" and
        scoreDateTime > '2016-01-16 00:00:00.000' and
        locationId in (
           'ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ',
           'ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRhatfHL4GYe0',
           'ChIJCes00a4I44kRKG8zB4KvYTM',
           'ChIJP-eRLq8I44kRKU6VOpTXqTM',
           'ChIJpbSR1a4I44kRemEzTpniis8',
           'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kRip2l7rjO2g4',
           'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kR5EWvRqJPUN4',
           'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kRRD_ZvPUmrGA',
           'ChIJjweq4h0G44kRWoCPQKPdrPM',
           'ChIJf2tVDB4G44kRTYjhl3sjm8M',
           'ChIJ_Vg4giEG44kRq2nvtjEn8yA',
           'ChIJP00qFSMG44kRyKcy2f_S12o'
        )
     group by locationId
   ) as y

on x.locationId = y.locationId;
```

The results look like the following:

```
mysql> source ../../query3.sql
+-----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------------------+
| locationId                  | count1 | count2 | count3 | count4 | count5 | commentCount | lastCommentDateTime     |
+-----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------------------+
| ChIJF1LAoqgI44kR5EWvRqJPUN4 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |            0 | NULL                    |
| ChIJpbSR1a4I44kRemEzTpniis8 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |            1 | 2016-04-19 11:17:41.836 |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ |      0 |      0 |      8 |      0 |      0 |            3 | 2016-04-17 19:28:10.435 |
| ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRhatfHL4GYe0 |      0 |      0 |      3 |      0 |      0 |            2 | 2016-04-17 23:22:55.254 |
+-----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the difference between your 2 queries are the `scoreDateTime` and `comments` criteria. One way to combine your queries is by moving these conditions to your `select` using conditional aggregation.

Also, mysql evaluates booleans to 1 or 0, so you can simplify your `sum` calls by removing your `if` statements.

```
select
    locationId,
    sum(score = 1 and scoreDateTime > '2016-04-16 21:38:51.843') count1,
    sum(score = 2 and scoreDateTime > '2016-04-16 21:38:51.843') count2,
    sum(score = 3 and scoreDateTime > '2016-04-16 21:38:51.843') count3,
    sum(score = 4 and scoreDateTime > '2016-04-16 21:38:51.843') count4,
    sum(score = 5 and scoreDateTime > '2016-04-16 21:38:51.843') count5,
    sum(comments != "") commentCount,
    max(case when comments != "" then scoreDateTime end) as lastCommentDateTime
    from
    scores
    where
    scoreDateTime > '2016-01-16 00:00:00.000' and
    locationId in (
        'ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRbNWHQkDkpGQ',
        'ChIJqZyf8O8F44kRhatfHL4GYe0',
        'ChIJCes00a4I44kRKG8zB4KvYTM',
        'ChIJP-eRLq8I44kRKU6VOpTXqTM',
        'ChIJpbSR1a4I44kRemEzTpniis8',
        'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kRip2l7rjO2g4',
        'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kR5EWvRqJPUN4',
        'ChIJF1LAoqgI44kRRD_ZvPUmrGA',
        'ChIJjweq4h0G44kRWoCPQKPdrPM',
        'ChIJf2tVDB4G44kRTYjhl3sjm8M',
        'ChIJ_Vg4giEG44kRq2nvtjEn8yA',
        'ChIJP00qFSMG44kRyKcy2f_S12o'
    )
    group by locationId
```

This query can take advantage of a composite index on `(locationId, scoreDateTime)`

Comment: Works great, Fuzzy Tree.  The improvements to the score counts also make perfect sense.  The only caveat is max(scoreDateTime) includes rows with empty comments.  I wanted to get the date from the most recent non-empty comment.

Comment: @jmelvin you can add case statement inside of `max` to only consider rows with comments see update

Comment: Perfect!  Did not know this was possible.  Fuzzy Tree, you are my SQL super hero!

Comment: @jmelvin glad to help :)